# How to use previous iTunes icon?

Tags: itunes, macos, icon

I'm have a MacBook Pro (x86_64) with OS X 10.8.5 (fully patched). When I got the MBP, the iTunes icon was a cool blue icon.

Recently, Apple changed it to red. The psychologist tell us red indicates anger, defiance and hostility, and its a bad color. Its why USAir changed their color scheme from the shades of red to shades of grey. I did not like red, but I did not feel compelled to move.

I got updates this week (July, 2015), and Apple changed the icon again:

[image]

I despise that cartoony look, and now I am compelled to move. That cartoony look is one of the reason I have held back from OS X 10.9 upgrade for my personal equipment (and even one of the reasons to abstain from iOS upgrades). This is a personal preference, and I understand only a subset of folks feel the same way.

I've been through iTunes preferences, but I don't see a way to change the icons.

How do I change the iTunes icons? Or how do I use the previous, blue icon?

---

Related, other reasons to abstain from the upgrade includes all the untested features and broken features that got added to 10.9. *Quod erat demonstrandum*: [iCloud Keychain and CVE-2015-1065](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204423). My keychain was never at risk through this vector, and it was a conscious decision to avoid the risk.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here are a few...

IMO The best way is to replace the actual *AppName.icns* file with the one from the older version, in this case it's: `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/iTunes.icns`

Select the application bundle and control-click *(right-click)* > **Show Package Contents**, then navigate to the *AppName.icns* file shown in the pathname above.  Note:  After replacing the *AppName.icns* file one may need to run `killall Finder` in a **Terminal** to force the updated *AppName.icns* file to show properly everywhere.  If it's not showing properly in the **Dock** afterwards run `killall Dock` in a **Terminal**.

Another way is to paste an image into the App's Info Sheet after selecting its icon at the top left of the Info Sheet.  Select the application bundle then control-click *(right-click)* > Get Info or  <kbd>⌘</kbd> -<kbd>I</kbd>.

Or use a third-party app that can assign an new *image/icon* to the application bundle.

Comment: Does Apple make the past icons available? If not, where do I get the old blue icon that Apple probably claims a copyright or trademark over?

Comment: `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/iTunes.icns` - that's kind of a neat trick, but kind of scary too. That means code signing can be bypassed for the package. More correctly, its a lack of semantic authentication. Lack of semantic authentication was one of the causes of Android's [Master Key](https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Forristal-Android-One-Root-to-Own-Them-All-Slides.pdf) flaw. It was even a problem back in the 1990s, with [SSLv2 and SSLv3](https://www.schneier.com/paper-ssl-revised.pdf). Its too bad we are not learning from our mistakes....

Comment: I routinely replace application bundle _.icns_ files, using scripts I've written, for many application that I do not like the icons for whatever the reason and have never had any problem afterwards running those applications.  So I'd have to say _code signing_ either doesn't come into play at this level or it's broken.  Now I'm not redistributing anything, this is just for use on my own system.

Comment: As to getting old _AppName.icns_ files, I get them from the Apps themselves either from a copy I have running in a virtual machine or if need be download one of the OS Updates or Application Updates (where applicable) and extract them from the _package_.  The latter method is kind of a waste of bandwidth so it just depends on how much you dislike the new icon as to what length you'll go.